# Abusing c++11 unique_ptr to execute code upon leaving the scope

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I want to use `std::unique_ptr`'s deleter to guarantee some code will execute upon leaving the scope. For example let's say I have a class `Event` with function `set_event()`.

I want to make sure that upon leaving the scope, the function `my_event.set_event()` will be called. I managed to get to something similar to this:

```
Event my_event;
auto releasing_function = [&my_event] (void*){my_event.set_event();};
std::unique_ptr<void, decltype(releasing_function)> safe_event((void*)1, releasing_function);
```

But I feel like we can do better. Maybe a one liner without this auto lambda function, or avoiding this ugly `(void*)1`. Maybe even removing `unique_ptr` completely.

Edit: I want to avoid utility classes. That's too easy :)

Comment: You could use something similar to `BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT`. Normally, you'd have an RAII class, though.

Comment: What's wrong with "too easy?"  It's better than misusing existing functionality like unique_ptr and thereby confusing the h**l out of the poor schmuck who has to maintain this at some point in the future.

Comment: Utility classes are the correct method. Writing code is about making it as easy as possible so in 6 days/weeks/months/years, whoever has to maintain it understands what it's doing. Clever is bad. Do the simplest, clearest thing.

Comment: @RobK: No new utility-classes needed when the standard ones are fine. Just needs a small maker-function.

Comment: whats really needed is try / finally in c++. I wonder if that's already been talked about :-)

Comment: First and foremost your program should be readable. Such tricks make your intent unclear and program difficult to maintain. Some novice programmers think that doing "clever" tricks make them cool. With experience you learn that coolest is to make your code readable and supportable, which is actually more clever.

Comment: @pm100 many of the use cases for a finally block are already covered in c++ by using RAII. class destructors are still called when exceptions occur, and so the cleanup that would be done in finally can be done in a destructor instead.

Comment: @YoungJohn - i know RAII ,.... but the fact that people keep inventing these scoping tricks for one-offs shows that the try / finally model is really,really useful. I am fully aware of the long debate about this topic, my comment was somewhat tongue in cheek

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define a maker-function in some header for ease-of-use:

```
template<class F> auto scope_guard(F&& f) {
    return std::unique_ptr<void, std::decay<F>::type>{(void*)1, std::forward<F>(f)};
}
```

And use it like:

```
auto unique = scope_guard([&](void*){/* cleanup here */});
```

Answer (score 0):

The original C++03 [ScopeGuard by Petru Marginean (and a little Andrei Alexandrescu)](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/generic-change-the-way-you-write-excepti/184403758) used all kinds of tricks. With C++11 you can just use a `std::function`, and lambda expressions for what you want done. E.g.

```
class Scope_guard
{
private:
    function<void()> cleanup_;
public:
    void release() { cleanup_ = []{}; }
    ~Scope_guard() { cleanup_(); }
    Scope_guard( function<void()> f )
        : cleanup_( move( f ) )
    {}
};
```

Disclaimer: code not touched by compiler.

Note: Apparently purists prefer to express this as a class template with a factory function, while simplists (simpletons?) like me prefer something like the above. But you get the idea.

Comment: clang tends to manage ok, but with gcc using std::function has a significant overhead, which may explain why people are reluctant.

Comment: I prefer to avoid utility classes. (Edited my question accordingly)

Comment: @MarcGlisse Why is there a difference in performance? Both would be using type-erasure and thus incurring a virtual call. What does gcc do differently?

Comment: Let me add a link: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59948 so people reading this in a while can check if it is still true. @Pradhan That's simply some missed optimizations in gcc.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it "by hand"?

```
{
    struct Guard {
        Event my_event;
        explicit Guard (Event my_event) : my_event (my_event) { }
        ~Guard () { my_event.set_event (); }
    };
    Guard guard {my_event};

    /* ... */

   // when scope is left, guard's destructor will be called
}
```

Comment: DRY: *Don't Repeat Yourself*

Comment: I prefer to avoid utility classes. (Edited my question accordingly)

Comment: @user972014, do you have a technical reason for wanting to avoid utility classes?

Comment: @RSahu that's too simple, so not allowing to express "cleverness" of the author